# Databricks SQL Query - without the use of looping

Tags: sql, databricks

I am trying to create a sql query on databricks to retrieve and tag records using some conditions.

I have a Policy table that looks like this:

| PolicyId | ClientId | AgentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1234 | C1234 | A1234 |
| P1235 | C1234 | A1235 |
| P1236 | C1234 | A1236 |
| P1237 | C1235 | A1234 |
| P1238 | C1235 | A1234 |
| P1239 | C1236 | A1237 |
| P1230 | C1236 | A1238 |
| P1241 | C1244 | A1238 |
| P1242 | C1255 | A1238 |

I also have a Agent main table:

| AgentId | BranchCode | AgentName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1234 | 10 | John |
| P1235 | 10 | Mike |
| P1236 | 10 | Peter |
| P1237 | 10 | Allan |
| P1238 | 11 | Roger |

I need to write a query in databricks sql that would determine Policies that belong to the same Customer but have different Agents that belong to the same BranchCode and tag them with a code ex: red. Furthermore, tag the policies that belong to the same Customer but have different Agents but doesnt share the same branch code as orange. Other policies that do not fall to these conditions are neutral or tagged white.

In the sample Policy data, PolicyIds - P1234,P1235,P1236 will be tagged red (since they are owned by the same Client but serviced by different agents under the same branch)
while P1237 and P1238 will be white. Lastly, P1239 and P1230 will be tagged orange. The other policies that do not belong to the same customer are also tagged ok / white  :

| PolicyId | ClientId | AgentId | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1234 | C1234 | A1234 | red |
| P1235 | C1234 | A1235 | red |
| P1236 | C1234 | A1236 | red |
| P1237 | C1235 | A1234 | white |
| P1238 | C1235 | A1234 | white |
| P1239 | C1236 | A1237 | orange |
| P1230 | C1236 | A1238 | orange |
| P1241 | C1244 | A1234 | white |
| P1242 | C1245 | A1234 | white |

I hope I explained this well, I can give more information if needed.

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: I don't know databrick but I think it would need to create at least two queries. First to JOIN tables and other to group rows by `ClientId` and count unique `AgentId` - and if it has more than one item then you would have to add tag `red`. But this may need nested queries: `SELECT` nested in `INSERT`. But I can't write it. As for me it would be simpler to write it with `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: How about policies that belong to one customer that have three agents, two of which share the the branch code? Red or orange? 

Comment: all 3 policies then will be flagged red. since each policies under the customer is compared to other policies to check condition.

Answer (score 1):

Just count the number of distinct agents and branches per policy.

```
SELECT PolicyId,
       case when count(distinct AgentId) = 1 then 'White'
            when count(distinct BranchCode) = 1 then 'Red'
            else 'Orange' end as Code
  FROM Policy
  JOIN Agent USING (AgentId)
 GROUP BY PolicyId;
```